# Passing a PFObject between views is causing values to be null

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, segue, pfobject

I'm new to Parse and iOS app development, so please excuse my question if it has an obvious answer.
In my app, the user needs to enter data across multiple views, and for resource efficiency, I am initiating the PFObject as a property in the first view and it is being handed via `prepareForSegue` to by each scene to its segue's destination view controller.

However, when checking the key-value pairs in the object, I noticed that they are not getting stored in the object. In the debugger, it shows the data in the "estimatedData" section. What is the cause of this? When I try to `saveInBackground` the object, it fails and says that the object is null.

Here is the code from the `FirstViewController.h` of the PFObject property declaration.
`@property (strong, nonatomic) PFObject *freshChow;`

I also call `@synthesize freshChow;` under the `@implementation` of the `FirstViewController.m`. 
I later initialize the object in an IBAction when a button is tapped.

```
- (IBAction)StartCookingProcess:(id)sender {
    freshChow = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"FoodItems"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Perform Init Segue" sender:self];
}
```

And the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Start Cooking Process"]) {
         Chow_Type_selection *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
         vc.freshChow = freshChow;
     }
 }
```

This code, with the exception of the `StartCookingProcess` method is repeated on the subsequent views.

Thanks,
Siddharth

Comment: First, get rid of the @synthesize and use `self.freshChow` to refer to the property.  Second, can you check with the debugger, is `freshChow` nil?  I suspect it isnt because of the message you are getting - it is more likely that you have stored nil in one of its values and that is what save is complaining about - post the error message

Comment: I managed to figure out the issue myself. It was problem in the conversion between UIImage and NSData for storing in PFFiles.